# field(check box) should be populate based on condition is related to other objects

Tags: workflow, validation, relationships

I have the field in Devfull called Is Direct on the Account object.  I need it populated under the following circumstances.

For a Pending or Active Partner (using the Partner Status field on the Account), we need to look at all of their “Active” (checkbox on the Solution/Accrediation object) related Solution/accreditation records.  If any of those records have the field “Direct” checked “True”, then the checkbox on the Account field Is Direct, should be checked “True”.  This box would be checked to False if none of the Solutions records have Direct checked True.

kindly suggest me to achieve this scenario.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are Solution/Accrediation and Account in Master Detail ?

Comment: No. Just Lookup relation ship between Solution/Accrediation and Account. actually i need trigger code for update this accout fields(is direct (true/false)) whenever changes(creating/updating) fields(active & direct ) in the Solution/Accrediation object. Many Solution/Accrediation records can have one(same) account. but when two fields(active & direct) in all records in Solution/Accrediation object which related to this accounts are check true(creating/ updating) then field(is direct) in account should be true.

Comment: None would write a complete trigger.Request you to start writing and post if you are stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need implement triggers for Account and Solution/accreditation objects

Comment: can you tell me what could be the condition

Comment: i need trigger code for update this accout fields(is direct (true/false)) whenever changes(creating/updating) fields(active & direct ) in the Solution/Accrediation object. Many Solution/Accrediation records can have one(same) account. but when two fields(active & direct) in all records in Solution/Accrediation object which related to this account check true(creating/ updating) then field(is direct) in account should be true